# Extended regex "." seems not to be matching everything

Tags: regex, linux, bash, posix-ere

I have a file containing this header `FIELD1     FIELD2 : 0x30070040` and a lot of junk characters (half the file's size). To get rid of all of them I execute these commands:

```
dos2unix -q -n file
sed -i $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' file #Removing every non-printable character (yes, dos2unix was not enough)
```

But then I end up having a file containing this odd header.
If I copy and paste it from shell it looks like this:

```
PFcount_01032019.txt0000777017777601777760116201541013436157760015052 0ustar  nfsnobodynfsnobody▒▒FIELD1   FIELD2 : 0x30070040
```

If I copy and paste from a text editor like VIM it looks like this:

```
PFcount_01032019.txt0000777017777601777760116201541013436157760015052 0ustar  nfsnobodynfsnobodyÿþFIELD1   FIELD2 : 0x30070040
```

**Note the two special characters just before FIELD1**.

Now I would like to end up with an header like this:

```
FIELD1   FIELD2
```

It is important to keep everything that is between `FIELD1` and `FIELD2` too because that is the fields separator of the file.
I thought about using this:

```
sed -i -r '1 s/.+(FIELD1.+) : 0x.+/\1/g' file
```

But apparently `.+FIELD1` does not match with `PFcount_01032019.txt0000777017777601777760116201541013436157760015052 0ustar  nfsnobodynfsnobody▒▒FIELD1` or `PFcount_01032019.txt0000777017777601777760116201541013436157760015052 0ustar  nfsnobodynfsnobodyÿþFIELD1` (whichever it is the true one), so I can't extract `\1` from the regex.

Shouldn't `.` match **every character**? Why it does not match with whatever come before `FIELD1`?

Comment: Can you add sample input file and expected output in question

Comment: `ustar`? Is it possible that the file you're dealing with is a tar archive?

Comment: @anubhava I've added the initial header of the file. it looks like a normal header, but if I execute the two commands I've listed the file's size halves

Comment: @melpomene nope, it's a regular text file

Comment: show us the characters before FIELD1 in the original file

Comment: `ÿþ` is `FF` `FE` in Latin-1, possibly a Unicode BOM being misinterpreted by vim having guessed the wrong character set. Obviously that's where the original file contents start, and this *is* a tar archive, though it may be a corrupted one.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley But how can a tar file (even if corrupted) containing those many hidden characters? Shouldn't tar be a compressed file type?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley you're right, by the way. I removed the Unicode BOM sequence before executing sed -i $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' and I end up with a correct header with no strange characters. If you want to post your solution as answer I will accept it